# Making a web-client in python to authenticate to router

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, web, webclient

I am trying to use python to make a web-client that will authenticate to the routers page (192.168.1.1) and once python has a successful session, do some stuff on the router.

Now the router doesn't use https. it uses http instead. The problem is that the router doesn't post the username and password plain text. It posts some hashed data and the server responds with hashed tokens. Because of this, I cannot use `requests.post(url, data= query)`.

I do not want to use selenium and mechanize. I want to do it pythons request module. Specifically, I do not want to use libraries that manipulate browsers. I want my application to be a web-client by itself.

Comment: Can you describe the hashes being sent and received in more depth?

Comment: I did bit of research and found out that they are called javascript challenges

Comment: Can you try setting the password to password and googling the hashes, see if it's just using it to hide the password, one UK ISP doesn't use https, and md5s the password to try to hide it.